# value of Bind variables in trigger oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers

I created a INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger (see below) on a view to insert a row in the underlying table .We need to proceed this route due to some application limitations .

```
      1  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_INSERT3 INSTEAD OF INSERT ON    ISG_SESSION_TEMPFEB15_VIEW REFERENCING NEW AS n FOR EACH ROW
      2  DECLARE
      3         IsgSession ISG_SESSION_TEMPFEB15%rowtype;
      4         row_count number;
      5         fldtime ISG_SESSION_TEMPFEB15.fld_timestamp%type;
      6         isgstart timestamp(6);
      7         isgstop timestamp(6);
      8  BEGIN
      9         select count(*) into row_count FROM  ISG_SESSION_TEMPFEB15
     10         WHERE isg_session_id = :n.isg_session_id
     11         AND nas_ip = :n.nas_ip
     12         AND mac_address = :n.mac_address;
     13  dbms_output.put_line('the value of row_count is '||ROW_COUNT);
     14  IF row_count IS NULL then
     15                fldtime:=to_timestamp_tz(:n.FLD_TIMESTAMP_TEMP,'RRRR-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi.SSXFFTZR') ;
     16                isgstart:=to_timestamp_tz(:n.ISG_START_TIME_TEMP,'RRRR-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi.SSXFFTZR') ;
     17                isgstop:=to_timestamp_tz(:n.ISG_STOP_TIME_TEMP,'RRRR-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi.SSXFFTZR') ;
     18  end if ;
     19  dbms_output.put_line('the values of fldtime,isgstart,isgstop are '||fldtime||','||isgstart||','||isgstop);
     20* end;
     21  /

   Trigger created.

    SQL> set serveroutput on
    SQL> insert into sanpalle.ISG_SESSION_TEMPFEB15_view(ISG_SESSION_ID,MAC_ADDRESS,NAS_IP,FLD_TIMESTAMP_TEMP,created_dte,isg_stop_time_temp) values 
      2    ('7000','7001','7002','2016-04-06T12:41:59.200Z','06-Apr-16 10.05.00.000000','2016-04-06T10:12:59.200Z');
   the value of row_count is 0
  the values of fldtime,isgstart,isgstop are ,,

  1 row created.

  SQL>
```

The issue is 1)the values of variables (fldtime,isgstart,isgstop) are shown as NULL
2) Even though it said "1 row created"  , actually the row is NOT inserted .
Can someone please tell me where i am going wrong ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: As you can see in the output, the value of row_count is zero as the select is not matching any record. Also, you are checking whether row_count is null in  your if instead of row_count is zero or not. So the code that assigns values of fldtime,isgstart,isgstor is not reached

Comment: Also, i dont see any insert statement inserting the new row in your trigger.

Comment: @cableload  - Put the row_count=0 resolved the issue .Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad 2) if u insert into VIEW with "insted of trigger" u need insert clause in this trigger to some table.

```
insert into my_table(a,b,c) values(:n.a, :n.b, :n.c);
```

(and i don't see commit, maybe u have autocommmit on - i don't know)

ad 1) condition

```
IF row_count IS NULL then
```

is false, bacause null is not 0,
if u have select count(*) then will have everytime number, then use condition:

```
IF (row_count = 0) then
```

- 1 = null = false
- 1 != null = false
- 0 = null = false
- null is null = true

null value in condition need only operator is / is not and can't be compered with anything else